# App crashes after Successful In-App-Purchase ios

Tags: ios, objective-c, crash, xcode6, in-app-purchase

I have successfully implemented `in App Purchase`.

But the problem is when `In-App purchase` succeeds my app crashses.

After successful transaction I am poping `ViewController` to `RootView`.

```
   case SKPaymentTransactionStatePurchased:
      [[SKPaymentQueue defaultQueue] finishTransaction:transaction];

            [self doRemoveAds];
```

My `doRemoveAds`

```
   - (void)doRemoveAds{
   [self.navigationController popToRootViewControllerAnimated:YES];
   }
```

I am unable to find the issue. When I run without `doRemoveAds()` it runs fine.

Comment: Did yo got any error log if yes then please add the log as well and also try to test project with NSZombe

Comment: I didnt get the log...as i am testing in device...and in simulator it is not working

Comment: check for testing without in-app on button click set  [self.navigationController popToRootViewControllerAnimated:YES]; and see what happen .

Comment: Get log with development provisioning.

Comment: If u use custom class for InAppPurchase, Then use the delegate or Block to notify your current ViewController about the successfully complete the InAppPurchase.And From that ViewController use   `[self.navigationController popToRootViewControllerAnimated:YES]` for navigate to RootViewController.

Answer (score 0):

So it doesn't have anything to do with the IAP. It's probably that your `self.navigationController = nil` or something wrong with your `RootVC`

Comment: No its not this...i write my code   [self.navigationController popToRootViewControllerAnimated:YES];  in viewWillAppear and is working fine